# Random access is denied errors in Visual Studio/TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I keep getting "access is denied" errors in Visual Studio when I run "get latest", or I try and check in code, or something like that. It seems to happen about 75% of the time, but if I try again a second time the error goes away and the operation works. I am using Visual Studio 2013. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have anti-virus running? Or maybe a VPN?

Comment: No I just have Windows Firewall running...

Comment: It sounds like something is interfering with the Get Latest sometimes, but not other times. Try creating a new workspace, at a different location on your disk, maybe `C:\SRC` or something simple like that, and do Get Latest again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I created a new workspace and I am not seeing the error any longer. Still not sure what the cause of the problem was, but this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I could check-in files, but for some reason when I performed a "Get Latest" action, I got access denied ...

The solution was to create a new workspace. I guess there is some corruption on the workspace, but I'm not sure where this may have occurred, or whether there is a configuration type file for workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a faulty proxy between you and the TFS server that is dropping your credentials. You should try connecting without the proxy...